# How to compute transfer entropy between different length time-series?

Tags: causality, entropy, information-theory

Is there a way to calculate transfer entropy between two time series having different lengths?
Given two time series:

$x=(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_n)$

$y=(y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_m)$,

where $n \ne m$.

Is there a way to calculate the transfer entropy from $x$ to $y$? Would it make sense to apply padding on the shorter series? Are there any specific methods?

Comment: Would this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12573/calculating-the-transfer-entropy-in-r

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Padding is not bad idea.